# rest_filter_response_fields does not apply filtering

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I am trying to apply the `_fields` filter query to my response, but for some reason `rest_filter_response_fields` does not filter as I expect it.

This is my PHP function:

```php
public function get_navigation_menus($request)
{
  $menus = wp_get_nav_menus();
  $response = rest_ensure_response($menus);

  return rest_filter_response_fields($response, null, $request);
}
```

When I send this request:

```
http://my.domain.com/wordpress/?rest_route=/custom/menus
```

I get the result from `wp_get_nav_menus`, a list of all available menus.

But as soon as I apply the `_fields` query like this.

```
http://my.domain.com/wordpress/?rest_route=/custom/menus&_fields=name,slug
```

I always get `null` as a result and this comes with the response:

```
Warning: array_intersect_key(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, object given in '/.../wordpress/wp-includes/rest-api.php' on line 780
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in '/.../wordpress/wp-includes/rest-api.php' on line 781
Warning: array_intersect_key(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, null given in '/.../wordpress/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 780
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in '/.../wordpress/wp-includes/rest-api.php' on line 781
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at '/.../wordpress/wp-includes/rest-api.php:780) in '/.../wordpress/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php' on line 1372
```

Comment: I don't know if this is related but according to [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_filter_response_fields/) the second parameter of `rest_filter_response_fields` should be an instance of `WP_REST_Server`, you are using `null`.

Comment: @JulienB. Indeed, that it correct, but I do not think that this causes any problems, because although `$server` is in the signature it is never used inside the function, so I just ignore it by passing `null`.